# Java: No suitable constructor found for Scanner(int)

Tags: java, object, netbeans, int, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a program that needs to generate a three-digit random number and then scan each of those numbers to compare against input for a guessing game.

I did initialize instance variables I just didn't put them here. I also have other methods as well, I don't think that affects what I'm having an issue with right now.

Honestly, I'm pretty new to programming and Java so it's probably a lot less complicated than I think. But my issue is that when I create a Scanner object called randScan and try to set it to scan my secretNumber object (which is generated randomly) I get an error that says "No suitable constructor found for Scanner(int)..." and then a lot of other errors underneath it (way too much to type out). I just don't understand why it wont scan the randomNumber since it is an int.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;     

// Generates three random single digit ints.  The first cannot be zero
// and all three will be different. Called by public method play()
public String generateSecretNumber()
{

    do 
    {   
        secretNumber = (int)(generator.nextInt(888)+101) ;              
        // scan the random integer
        Scanner randScan = new Scanner(secretNumber) ;  //<- THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
        num1 = randScan.nextInt();                      // scan the first digit
        num2 = randScan.nextInt() ;                     // scan the second digit
        num3 = randScan.nextInt() ;                     // scan the third digit
    }   
    while ( num1 == 0 || num1 == num2 ||
         num2 == num3 || num1 == num3) ;   // re-generate if any digits are the same

    return number ;
```

Comment: Why do you need the `Scanner`?

Comment: I need to use it to compare against another 3-digit input so I was using Scanner to separate each number separately and contrast it against the three-digit guessed input so I can print out "hints" for the digits they guessed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just trying to get the three digits of `secretNumber` (as integer values), you can just use:

```
num1 = secretNumber / 100;
num2 = (secretNumber / 10) % 10;
num3 = secretNumber % 10;
```

There's no need to convert to use a string here. On the other hand, if you don't need `secretNumber` itself, surely you just need to generate three numbers between 1 and 9. The simplest way to do *that* is to use something like:

```
List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    digits.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(digits, generator);
```

... then use the first three values in the list:

```
num1 = digits.get(0);
num2 = digits.get(1);
num3 = digits.get(2);
```

Comment: The reason I was doing it that way is because the method requires a String type output so I have to turn that number into a String in order to return the value from the method. But you have a great point about the three digits, and it is much simpler to just divide and use mod. Perhaps I can just turn each number into a String separately and then concatenate them into one.

Answer (score 1):

You should deal `secretNumber` by

```
String secretNumberString = new String(secretNumber);
```

as a String and after then You need to try [Scanner#hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)
According to the Doc

```
Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be 
interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt() method.
The scanner does not advance past any input.
```

So I guess it may resolve your problem
So your code would be like

```
secretNumber = (int)(generator.nextInt(888)+101) ;              
       String secretNumberString = new String(secretNumber);
       Scanner randScan = new Scanner(secretNumberString) ;  
        if(randScan.hasNextInt())
            num1 = randScan.nextInt();
           //Remaining code
```

Answer (score 0):

[Available constructors for scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner(File source) 
Scanner(File source, String charsetName) 
Scanner(InputStream source) 
Scanner(InputStream source, String charsetName) 
Scanner(Readable source) 
Scanner(ReadableByteChannel source)
Scanner(ReadableByteChannel source, String charsetName)
Scanner(String source)
```

For single digits, you should probably pass a string with `String.valueOf(yourInt)`